# If I expire a job listing will I still be able to communicate with candidates who have applied?

Tags: support, jobs

Will anything change other than the fact that the posting will no longer be public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely still contact and communicate with the candidates through Stack Overflow Careers after expiring a job listing! The listing will be moved to the "Expired" section when looking at your job listings, but you can still view it as well as all candidates that applied while it was live.